# Ubuntu stops at booting

Tags: ubuntu, boot, system-recovery, kde-neon

My laptop came with ubuntu lts preinstalled, i installed kde desktop&co via neon package sources. I've been using it for couple of months well-working. I left my laptop for acouple of minutes, and as i went back, the task bar and the Window-Borders were away, alt+tab did nothing , alt+f2 did nothing, pressing win key did nothing. I had a Terminal in fullscreen open, so i entered `firefox`, and it launched properly. I closed the firefox vie clicking to background terminal and hitting ctrl+c. Then, in order to reboot i entered `shutdown now`. After the system was shut down, i rurned it back on. The kde neon splash screen appeared like everytime, but after that just a blinking cursor abbeared at the top left corner. I can't type anything, If i press the Powerbutton, the splasch screen appears and the System shuts down.

Comment: When you restart and you see the blinking cursor can you try CTRL+ALT+F1? If that brings you to a shell it seems like ubuntu is booting correctly but your DM isn't running at start up.

Comment: This helped, thank you. I Updated my System in the Shell and now kde starts.